# Designer Workflow Error : List item not found

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow in Moss 2007 for a document library i.e holds uploaded document upto 365 days then sends to subsite(Archive) and delete the list item.I am able to pause for 365 days and able to move the document to subsite(Archive site),But when the workflow comes to Delete step it is encountering error as "List item not found".Can any on help me in solving this issue.